# Can ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator be used outside the context of a validator?

Tags: java, spring, validation

I've googled and checked the Javadocs on this problem, but I'm not finding much.

I'm trying to use some user validation messages in a `validationMessages.properties` file outside of the actual JSR-303 validator that they normally get used in (they work fine in the normal validation cycle.)

Specifically, I'm trying to use this message:

```
javax.validation.constraints.Size.message=This field has a maximum length of {max}.
```

Normally I would use a typical ResourceBundleMessageSource bean:

```
@Autowired
private ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;

result.append(messageSource.getMessage("javax.validation.constraints.Size.message", new Object[]{maxLength}, "", null));
```

But in this case, because of the `{max}` parameter I get this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't parse argument number: max
java.text.MessageFormat.makeFormat(MessageFormat.java:1420)
java.text.MessageFormat.applyPattern(MessageFormat.java:479)
java.text.MessageFormat.<init>(MessageFormat.java:381)
org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceSupport.createMessageFormat(MessageSourceSupport.java:159)
org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource.getMessageFormat(ResourceBundleMessageSource.java:371)
org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource.resolveCode(ResourceBundleMessageSource.java:257)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource.getMessageInternal(AbstractMessageSource.java:205)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource.getMessage(AbstractMessageSource.java:113)
```

The validator message has a `{max}` where a normal parameterized message would have a {1}.

I figured out pretty quickly that for a validation message I need to run it through the validation message processing, not the "regular" Spring message processing.   However, I can't figure out how to do that.   The `ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator` includes only an `interpolate(String message, Context context)` function, nothing directly accessible for the purpose of building a message.    I can't find any documentation or example of how the context object gets built, so I'm kind of stuck.    Can anyone tell me how to do this (interpolate a validator message) outside of the entire validation process, in a stand-alone way?